Можноли сделать донат звёздами в телеграмм бота с помощью telebot?
Так как недавно сделали возможность донатить звёздочки в телеграме то в ботах появилась возможность сделать донат этих звёздочек. И с этим у меня возник вопрос на который я немогу не как найти ответ
Можноли сделать донат звёздочками в Боте если он сделан на telebot?
Знаю что можно сделать такую вещь на aiogram, но мне нужно на telebot Возможно-ли такое сделать?
Ну или же можно это как-нибудь через API самого telegram? Буду благодарен если скините какие-нибудь статью по этому поводу

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
